# User preferences database design

Tags: database-design

I can't decide how to solve the following situation: I have the `users` table which has basic attributes like `id`, `username`, `email`, etc, and I want to record the user's selected categories. After reading through similar questions here on SO, and extensive googling I came up with few options:

**a)** Create the table `user_categories` which would have these fields:

```
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | user_id | sport | music | books |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     123 |     0 |     1 |     1 |
|  2 |     543 |     1 |     0 |     0 |
|  3 |     645 |     1 |     1 |     0 |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

In my case the "categories" (sport, music, books) would just be a boolean type - YES/NO (1/0) which would denote if a user has this category selected or not. Also, there will be no more than 20 of these "categories" (right now in my design I have 12 - and none of them will be deleted, there is just a possibility some new (more fine-grained) will be added).

**b)** Create the table `categories` which would for example look like this:

```
+----+----------+
| id | category |
+----+----------+
|  1 | sport    |
|  2 | music    |
|  3 | books    |
+----+----------+
```

and then the `user_categories` table would look like this:

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
| id | user_id | category_id | category_value |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
|  1 |     123 |           1 |              0 |
|  2 |     123 |           2 |              1 |
|  3 |     123 |           3 |              1 |
+----+---------+-------------+----------------+
```

Can you tell me which of these two would you use? (Or if I'm totally wrong, can you suggest a better solution?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **a)** might be viable if:

- you absolutely have to avoid JOINs (for performance reasons)
- and categories are static, so you don't have to constantly add new columns to `user_categories` (which is expensive, and depending on a DBMS could require an exclusive lock on the whole table, effectively making it unavailable for the duration of the alteration).

I'd modify your original design for **b)** and drop the `category_value`. So, a user is in the category if the corresponding row exists in `user_categories` and not in the category if it doesn't. This allows:

- easy addition of new categories
- and can actually save space (and therefore cache performance) if most users are in a minority of all categories,
- but *may* require more JOINing (and then again may not - depends on what you actually need to query for).

I suspect **b)** would be a better fit for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer the second approach which is generic enough to practically add categories with zero application layer change in terms of inserting and querying. The first approach requires a schema change which is the costliest one and requires propagation to all the layers .

We followed a similar approach in one of our enterprise projects with adding attributes to business objects. That case was a bit complex where the data type of attributes is not the same, so we added one column per data type (attr_id, bit_attr_value, int_attr_value ...). This has given enormous flexibility for defining attributes at runtime through an admin UI with zero app layer code change.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are possible and OK.

Generally, if you know that you will never need to add extra category next to "sport", "music", "books" then you can simply go with 1 table solution.

If you suppose that the number of categories (en thus fields) will grow up - then go for the second. Add records is always easier then fields. You will never need to change the structure of tables.

In your case when you know that you probably will add some fields in the future you'd better choose for the second way.